# Creating groups and need to save devise user to database in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating groups in rails app and need to save the user to database (i think so at least) so that i can show created by user email on the show page. I cant use current_user because it changes with every login. below is the code which i use and results in `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in GroupsController` . So i need to know how do i save the user to database (if thats the right way) to make this work correctly or how do i make it work correctly ?

## user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :groups
end
```

## group model

```
 class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

## devise-user migration (only the necessary part)

t.has_many :groups

## group migration

```
t.belongs_to :user
```

## group controller create method

```
def create
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @group = @user.groups.build(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @group.save
        format.html { redirect_to @group, notice: 'Group was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @group, status: :created, location: @group }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @group.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

## group controller new method

```
 def new
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @group = @user.groups.build(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @group }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setup here doesn't make much sense. In the new action you shouldn't search for a user. Most likely if your routing is used correctly, you wouldn't even get a parma[:id]. Same goes in create method, which (as the name says) should create a new user record not search for it.

The new action should only create a new record (without saving) like

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  ... # no building of groups here, since record is still empty, does not even have an id
end
```

now it should use this user object to render the input form in new.html.erb

After the user submits the new form, he ends in the create action. Now you create a new user and actually save in the database:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    # maybe create some groups here
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render :action => "new"
  end
end
```

To this point this has not much to do with devise and user authentication.

This is only a rough overview to show you the most common process (as you would find in any good RoR tutorial)
Otherwise your question isn't very clear about what exactly you want to do and what this has to do with devise and current_user. 
Most likely you will have some controllers and actions that let a user see his email, groups and other user specific data. In this case those controllers will have to use current_user (after the login).
Many projects have additional functionality for admin interfaces that will allow a specific user to see lists of users and their data. In this case you will use current_user to make sure the user has admin rights and other find and search functionality to show data of administrated users.

Comment: well i am not trying to create new User here, i am trying to associate the existing user with a new group. how do i do that