# has_many :through rails

Tags: ruby, activerecord, associations

I want to get user1 to accept requests from other users to join user1s post as contributors and be listed out if user1 accepts them

Can't seem to get it to work - Here's my setup:

```
has_many :through
```

I'm thinking:

> post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    #Join table associations
    has_many :group_requests, class_name:  "Group",
                                  foreign_key: "requester_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
    has_many :group_users, class_name:  "Group",
                                   foreign_key: "accepted_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
    has_many :requester, through: :group_requests
    has_many :accepted, through: :group_users

def request(other_post)
    group_requests.create(accepted_id: other_post.id)
end

# Unfollows a user.
def unrequest(other_post)
    group_requests.find_by(accepted_id: other_post.id).destroy
end

# Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
def accepted?(other_post)
    requesting.include?(other_post)
end
```

> user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  #Join table associations
  belongs_to :group
```

> group model

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :requester, class_name: "Post"
    belongs_to :accepted, class_name: "Post"
    validates :requester_id, presence: true
    validates :accepted_id, presence: true
end
```

> CreatePosts Migration

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :content
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

> DeviseCreateUsers Migration

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.integer :post_id
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
```

> AddUserIdToPosts

```
class AddUserIdToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer
    add_index :posts, :user_id
  end
end
```

> CreateGroup Migration

```
class CreateGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :groups do |t|
      t.integer :requester_id
      t.integer :accepted_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :groups, :requester_id
    add_index :groups, :accepted_id
    add_index :groups, [:requester_id, :accepted_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

> Post Controller

```
  def accepted
    @title = "Accepted"
    @post  = Post.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.accepted.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_accepted'
  end

  def requester
    @title = "Requesters"
    @post  = Post.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.requester.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_requester'
  end

private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :image)
    end
```

> Post Show

```
  <% @post ||= current_user(@post) %>
  <div class="stats">
    <a href="<%= accepted_post_path(@post) %>">
      <strong id="following" class="stat">
        <%= @post.accepted.count %>
      </strong>
      following
    </a>
    <a href="<%= requester_post_path(@post) %>">
      <strong id="followers" class="stat">
        <%= @post.requester.count %>
      </strong>
      followers
    </a>
  </div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: whats your problem? its not clear

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction > want to get many users to join a post

Comment: when im in the console : i dont get anything back when i type in >> p.user_ids

Comment: I think your model is correct. Try to type `p.users` (for p being a Post) in your console, you should have your list of same-group users.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this ---

as i think p is your post and you want to get all user_ids.

```
   p.group_members.map{|gm|gm.user_id} #list of all ids in array

    ### OR try this

   p.users  #list of all users in array

   #if you want to collect ids then

  p.users.collect(&:id)
```

I think it should be helpful for you

Comment: try to add in group class -  has_many:  users , :foreign_key => "accepted_id", :class_name => "User"   -------------------                                                                                                     and run p.users in console if its not work then please give me the error message of console

Comment: Im getting >> undefined method `requester' for nil:NilClass >> @users = @user.requester.paginate(page: params[:page]) ?

Comment: Your mistake is in your post controller in the requester method where you calculating user--this is instance variable so default its value is nil you need to calculate user .

Comment: for further help please show me what is in params and your post migration. otherwise you could find current user id by session[:user_id]

Comment: Just updated with params and migrations @ArvindKumar

Comment: you can replace the line in requester method of post controller   @users =  current_user(@post).requester.paginate(page: params[:page])

Comment: I'm thinking of just using Devise Invitable in the post model and create a way a user can send a like request - then list out all the users who liked a particular post ?? Would that be better than has_through?